# Django: customizing the message after a successful form save

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-messages

whenever I save a model in my Admin interface, it displays the usual "successfully saved message." 
However, I want to know if it's possible to customize this message because I have a situation where I want to **warn** the user about what he just saved and the implications of these actions.

```
class PlanInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormset):
    def clean(self):
        ### How can I detect the changes?  
        ### (self.changed_data doesn't work because it's an inline)
        ### and display what he/she just changed at the top AFTER the successful save?

class PlanInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Plan
    formset = PlanInlineFormset
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django (> version 1.2) uses the messages framework for admin messages. You can add additional messages using that interface. Here's an example:

```
from django.contrib import messages

class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # your normal ModelAdmin stuff goes here

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # add an additional message
        messages.info(request, "Extra message here.")
        super(SomeModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

To detect changes to the object being saved, you should be to override the [save_model method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) of ModelAdmin, and compare the object the method is passed to the version currently in the database. To do this in the case of inlines, you can override the [save_formset method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset). A possible approach might look like (untested code):

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # your normal ModelAdmin stuff goes here

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        if not change:
            formset.save()
        else:
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)

            for instance in instances:
                try:
                    # if you've got multiple types of inlines
                    # make sure your fetching from the 
                    # appropriate model type here
                    old_object = SomeOtherModel.get(id=instance.id)
                except SomeOtherModel.DoesNotExist:
                    continue

                if instance.field_x != old_object.field_x:
                    messages.info(request, "Something Changed")

            instance.save()

        formset.save_m2m()
```

Comment: Just a quick question,  message.warning(..., '...') still displays as if it's still a normal successful message. Is there a way to make it RED like it's raising an Exception error?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Django 1.2 or newer, the messages framework may hold the answer.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/