# How can I use Django's messages framework to append to an admin success message from an inline form?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-admin, message

We have something like the following:

```
class SecondaryItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SecondaryItem
    form = SecondaryItemForm

class PrimaryItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = SecondaryItemInline,
```

What I would like to do is to add a custom message to the default Django admin success message from the clean method of `SecondaryItemForm`.  I am seeing how to do this from `PrimaryItemAdmin` using `save_model`, but not seeing anything on doing this from an inline form.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is possible using the following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.message_user - but you need access to the `request` object. You will be able to do this from the inline NOT the form.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the issue.  If I discover something while cleaning the inline forms, I need to be able to report it after saving.  Really don't understand why they chose not to make the request available in forms.

Comment: Haven't found a direct way of doing what I want, but using the following answer, I can duplicate a few things in the save_formset modeladmin method and make it work.  Not ideal, but sufficient.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548325/django-customizing-the-message-after-a-successful-form-save