# Is there any way to save success message in context in django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, view

I created a model form.Is it possible to add some message in context in `views.py` ?
Actually i want to display a success message in template page when form is submitted and data added in database.

for example i want to do this:

```
if form.save:
    msg = 'Data inserted successfully'
context = {'msg': msg,}
```

I want to save success message in my context so therefore i will show in my template page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing the message after model save, you can follow this Stack Over Flow Question - [Django: customizing the message after a successful form save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548325/django-customizing-the-message-after-a-successful-form-save?rq=1)

Please this [messages functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) given by django framework for onetime messages. This is the second answer provided for the above question. There are a lot of ways mentioned in the documentation that could be implemented.

Simplest one is - 
In Views.py:

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Data inserted successfully.')
```

In template:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: this is not related to my question.it is about admin success message customization.I want to display message on template page

Comment: @habib you should definitly re-read this answer and the docu it points to - the messages framework is not "about admin success messages", it's a general tool used to solve exactly the kind of problem you have.